# How to find the maximum value in entire Excel workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet, array-formulas

I have an Excel workbook with many sheets (today, about thirty, and growing every day). Each worksheet is named for the date of the data it contains (e.g., *02-10*, *02-11*, etc.). In cell A2 of each worksheet is a number, and I want to write a formula that looks at cell A2 in every worksheet, and returns the largest one.

I created a list of the current worksheets and named it *DayWorksheets*, and I attempted to get the value using the formula

`{=MAX(INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&DayWorksheets&"'!A2"),0))}` (brackets shown to denote array formula).

But the result every time is "10," which is the number in cell A2 of the first worksheet in the named range (and it's not the largest). What am I doing wrong here? I've seen a few other formulas around, the likes of

`=VLOOKUP(C1,INDIRECT("Sheet"&MATCH(TRUE,COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Sheet"&ROW(INDIRECT("1:10"))&"!A2:A100"),B1)>0,0)&"!A2:B100"),2,0)`,

but I don't quite understand the purpose of the `countif` function in there. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [formula with 3D-reference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-3-d-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-HP010102346.aspx) like this:

```
=MAX(Sheet1:Sheet30!A2)
```

1. Click the cell where you want to enter the function.
2. Type `=` (equal sign), enter the name of the function (`MAX`), and then type
   an opening parenthesis.
3. Click the tab for the first worksheet that you want to reference.
4. Hold down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and click the tab for the last worksheet that you
   want to reference.
5. Select the cell or range of cells that you want to reference (`A2` in your case).
6. Complete the formula (add closing parenthesis), and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for finding the max across the workbook. My goal is to look through each worksheet for a value in range, say, B1:B1000, and then return the content of A2 if the value is found. Unfortunately, the 3D formula won't work for this, and I dont understand the formula I put in the question well enough to use it. Is this a problem for another thread?

Comment: @T6J2E5, yes, please, put it as new quetsion. Since you have 30+ sheets, personally, it would be _much_ simplier to use UDF vba function for this rather than sophisticated formula like in your original question.

Comment: A follow-up to @simoco and a tip to everyone else. I did end up solving this problem with a simple user-defined VBA function using the `Range.Find` method and a for-next loop to go through each worksheet. Thanks again, simoco!